# Tabela não é reconhecida no join

Tags: sql, query, oracle, pl-sql

Mudei a query, porque a tabela TAKB437T_HIER_SAP não é para ser usada. Isso veio depois, mas continuo com problemas de reconhecer no join. Essa é query, sendo que **GE** é onde estou tendo problemas. Abaixo a query atual

```
SELECT 
           COMP2.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN AS COD_UO,
           COMP2.ATSF_CO_PORT_EXT AS DESC_UO,
           COMP2.FKSF_SUPERIOR_HIER AS COD_SUP,
           CASE
              WHEN COMP2.FKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL = EMP.FKSF_FUNCAO  THEN 1
           END
              AS SUPERIOR,
           QUAL.PKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL AS COD_CARGO,
           QUAL.ATND_FUNCAO_SAP AS COD_CARGO_SAP,
           NVL(QUAL.ATSF_FUN_PORT_EXT, 'NÃO CADASTRADO') AS DESC_CARGO,
           EMP.PKSF_CHAPA AS COD_FUNC,
           EMP.ATSF_NOME AS DESC_FUNC, 
           GE.ATSF_NOME AS GESTOR,
           NVL(E.ATSF_GRAU, EMP.FKSF_GRAU) AS GRAU_FUNC,
              EMP.ATND_SALAR1 AS SAL_ATUAL,
           COMP2.NIVEL
        FROM     
        ( 
            SELECT PKSF_CHAPA, ATSF_NOME, FKSF_FUNCAO, FKND_COMP_ORGAN, ATDT_DEMISSAO, ATND_SALAR1, FKSF_GRAU
            FROM PANA101V_EMPREGADO
            WHERE PKSF_CHAPA NOT IN(    SELECT PKND_NUMERO_PESSOAL 
                                        FROM TAKB132T_EMPREGADO_AFASTAMENTO 
                                        WHERE FKND_MOTIVO IN(6, 7) AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ATDT_DE AND ATDT_ATE)
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT '999', 'POSIÇÃO NÃO OCUPADA', '999',COMP2.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN, NULL, NULL, NULL 
            FROM 
               DUAL, (    SELECT   COMP.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN,
                        COMP.ATSF_CO_PORT_EXT,
                        CASE
                        WHEN COMP.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN <> 20061607 THEN  NVL(TRIM(COMP.FKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL), 999)
                        END AS FKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL,
                        COMP.FKSF_SUPERIOR_HIER,
                        LEVEL AS NIVEL,
                        COMP.ATSF_DT_CANCEL_CO
                 FROM   PANA004T_COMPONENT COMP
                --WHERE   COMP.ATSF_DT_CANCEL_CO = 0
           CONNECT BY   PRIOR COMP.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN = COMP.FKSF_SUPERIOR_HIER
           START WITH   COMP.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN = NVL(20047213 ,20061607)) COMP2

           WHERE COMP2.FKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL = '999'
           AND   COMP2.ATSF_DT_CANCEL_CO = 0)
            )      EMP

            LEFT JOIN(SELECT EMP.ATSF_NOME, EMP.PKSF_CHAPA FROM PANA101V_EMPREGADO EMP 
                      LEFT JOIN PANA004T_COMPONENT C ON EMP.FKND_COMP_ORGAN = C.FKSF_SUPERIOR_HIER)GE ON EMP.PKSF_CHAPA = GE.PKSF_CHAPA

        LEFT JOIN TAKB100T_EMPREGADO E ON E.PKND_NUMERO_PESSOAL = EMP.PKSF_CHAPA
              LEFT JOIN
                 PANA001T_QUALIFICA QUAL
              ON EMP.FKSF_FUNCAO = QUAL.PKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL
           RIGHT JOIN
               (    SELECT   COMP.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN,
                        COMP.ATSF_CO_PORT_EXT,
                        CASE
                        WHEN COMP.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN <> 20061607 THEN  NVL(TRIM(COMP.FKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL), 999)
                        END AS FKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL,
                        COMP.FKSF_SUPERIOR_HIER,
                        LEVEL AS NIVEL,
                        COMP.ATSF_DT_CANCEL_CO
                 FROM   PANA004T_COMPONENT COMP
                WHERE   COMP.ATSF_DT_CANCEL_CO = 0
           CONNECT BY   PRIOR COMP.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN = COMP.FKSF_SUPERIOR_HIER
           START WITH   COMP.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN = NVL(20047213 ,20061607)) COMP2

           ON COMP2.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN = EMP.FKND_COMP_ORGAN 

           LEFT JOIN(  SELECT
                 C.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN, E.ATSF_NOME
             FROM PANA101V_EMPREGADO E 
             INNER JOIN PANA004T_COMPONENT C ON E.FKND_COMP_ORGAN = C.FKSF_SUPERIOR_HIER) GE
             ON GE.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN = EMP.FKND_COMP_ORGAN
             --WHERE C.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN = 20000988


        WHERE   ( QUAL.PKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL NOT IN ( 'MU2', '8WY')  OR  QUAL.PKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL IS NULL )
          AND   COMP2.ATSF_DT_CANCEL_CO = 0
    ORDER BY    COMP2.NIVEL, COMP2.ATSF_CO_PORT_EXT, SUPERIOR;
```

A questão toda é o Gestor que está vindo no result da query, é o mesmo que o funcionário, ou seja, se DESC_FUNC = MANOEL então GESTOR = MANOEL e assim por diante. O que fiz de errado na minha query?

OBS: Na tabela COMPONENT eu tenho a chave PKSF_COMP_ORGAN e nessa mesma tabela eu tenho FKSF_SUPERIOR_HIER que diz que esse código é o superior. Porem COMPONENT é o que chamamos de UO, que não é uma pessoa, mas uma espécie de área, onde na tabela EMPREGADOS eu posso ter vários empregados em um UO. Isso éo que eu tentei colocar na query.

Comment: Qual versão do oracle?

Comment: @BrunoWarmling, 11g

Comment: No segundo join tente um JOIN no lugar do IN , até a 11 , a 12 não sei este subselect não permite a referência a tabela original. Nestes casos como este do supervisor prefiro o uso de functions o sql fica mais limpo , basta escrever uma function com um sql rápido.